# How we can make weekly calendar block with ajax?

Tags: datetime

[image]

How we can make weekly calendar in drupal 7 module same as attach screenshot?

**My R&D**

I am using jQuery week calendar (https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) .

Comment: You're not going to get a tutorial on here for a question like this.. But I'd output the dates and info in an ```Unformatted list``` view and use php to build the html in the view's tpl file. It takes quite a while to work out how to do this sort of thing the first time.

Comment: Hi Niall,

I am trying to make week calendar but i am getting date only in posted node , I am also want date in remaining if no entry will available. 

If you know any solution plz let me know.

Comment: Do you know how to work with tpl files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have achieved weekly calendar functionality using the php date function .

```
  $date = date('m/d/Y'); 
  // parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp 
  $ts = strtotime($date);
  // find the year (ISO-8601 year number) and the current week
  $year = date('o', $ts);
  $week = (int)date('W', $ts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use calendar module (requires views module). Calendar module comes with bunch of blocks (block views) available and you can set for them to use AJAX instead of refreshing page. With views you can do a lot of customization.

Comment: I have checked calendar module with views . But i am not getting how we can make weekly calendar with carousel ?  If you have any suggestion or any logic Please share.

Comment: Well, it's not out of box solution. You'll have to add some JS/CSS to make it work..